# Matplotlib Countour not Connected

Tags: contour

As a Python novice and trying to visualize the curve X**2*Y + X*Y**2 - X**4 - Y**4 = 0 with Matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from sympy import *
from numpy import *

delta = 0.025

p = arange(-0.5, 1.5, delta)
q = arange(-0.5, 1.5, delta)
X, Y = meshgrid(p, q)
Z = X**2*Y + X*Y**2 - X**4 - Y**4

fig, ax = subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, [0], colors ='k')
ax.set_title('x**2*y + x*y**2 - x**4 - y**4')

show()
```

the result is that the plot is not connected, whereas mathematically, it should be so. How can the level set be connected?

Answer (score 1):

It's a year later, but for future reference: You just have to choose a smaller stepsize delta. With your `delta = 0.025` your get the disconnected picture:

[image]

With `delta = 0.001` you get a more accurate connected picture:

[image]